# react native jest with es6 and typescript without emulator only browser

Tags: react-native, ts-jest, react-native-web

I am trying to follow the documentation [jest webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack) and use `ts-jest` in my project

I am getting error in this syntax

```
import typeof
```

Below is the full error

```
Details:

    C:\Users\.....\git\app\node_modules\react-native\index.js:14
    import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      3 |  */
      4 |
    > 5 | import 'react-native';
        | ^
      6 | import React from 'react';
      7 | import App from '../App';
      8 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/App-test.tsx:5:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.965 s
Ran all test suites.
```

below is the jest config

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  transform: {
    '\\.ts$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: './babel.config.web.js' }],
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js',
  },
};
```

below is the babel.config.web.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "react-native-web",
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin"
  ]
};
```

This is the tsx file code

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```